# angular 2+ url case insensitive except params

Tags: angular

i'm using lazy loading.i wanna make Url insensitive except params.

app-routing.module.ts

```
  {
  path: 'user/:Id',
 loadChildren: '../app/user/user.module#userModule',
 }
```

user-routing.module.ts

```
const playerRoutes: Routes = [
       {
       path: '', pathMatch: 'full',
      component: userComponent
    },
     {
       path: 'friends',
      component: userfriendsComponent
    },
]
```

In userComponent.ts  and userfriendsComponent.ts  im passing the id to service and get the data.

userComponent.ts

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
 this.service.getUserdata(params[['Id']);
 });
```

userfriendsComponent.ts

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
 this.service.getUserFriendsdata(params[['Id']);
 });
```

for example id = aBcDeF;
   my routing path is 
  http://localhost:4200/user/aBcDeF and 
    http://localhost:4200/user/aBcDeF/friends

i wanna make case insensitive url except id;
  i have tried the following code but it changed whole url into 
 lowercase.

app.module.ts

```
 import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree , UrlSerializer} from 
    '@angular/router';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
 parse(url: string): UrlTree {
return super.parse(url.toLowerCase());
}


@NgModule({
imports: [
  ...
],
declarations: [AppComponent],
providers: [
    {
        provide: UrlSerializer,
        useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
    }
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  }
```